# What is the complexity class for each one of the following functions

Tags: computational-complexity

What is the complexity class for each one of the following functions:

$a) (n^3+n^2 \log n)(\log n+1) + (10 \log n+7)(n^3+3)$

$b) (2n + n^2)(4n^3 + 4n)$

$c) (n^n + n2^n + 3n)(n! + 6n)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Please check that I edited your question correctly as I guessed at what you meant on some of them! Regards

Answer (score 0):

If your question mean is "what is the complexity of these functions":

a) $O(n^3\log n) \rightarrow a\in P$

b) $O(n^5) \rightarrow b\in P$

c) $O(n^nn!) \rightarrow c\in EXP$

Comment: It seems  $ n! $ is missing in $ c) $